# Several attempts at cranking required to start car

Tags: starting

Every time I get in and turn the key nothing happens. After turning the key a number of times, it will start up as normal. I have had a new battery, and new wiring to the starter motor installed, and also gotten a new key. Still the same thing is happening. My car is a 2006 Kia Sedona diesel.

Comment: Describe the "nothing" in more detail, please. Do dashboard lights and other electronics come on? When you turn the key to crank (furthest position), do you hear a clicking and no other sound? Does the starter motor operate without the engine "catching"? Does the starter only operate sometimes? Is the noise of the starter unusually loud?

Answer (score 1):

If the engine does not turn over on the first few times of turning the key, then in the light of what you have already had done, the switch on the bottom of your ignition key barrel may be at fault, or you starter motor solonoid sticking. If the engine turns over but does not start, and you have let the glow plug warning light go out, then an ECU relay defect may be your answer.